# why the linked css don't works in my workmate if its the ssame project that mine? laravel

Tags: laravel, layout, href, assets, laravel-blade

I pass a project to a workmate. its develop in Laravel.

we have a problem with the layout this is the code:

```
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <meta name="title" content="Título de la WEB">
    <meta name="description" content="Descripción de la WEB">

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/estilos.css">      
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous">


</head>
```

I am linking the css that is in ../public/css/
with:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/estilos.css">
```

my workmate have the same code, the only different thing in the project is the name of the project folder but for it linking don't works for her, she have to put:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="public/css/estilos.css">
```

we can no work with that problem because it's a repository. we have the same problem with the images on /public/images/

i proved with

```
{{ HTML::style('css/bootstrap.min.css') }}
```

but throws

```
Class 'HTML' not found (View: G:\xammp\htdocs\fractalpage\resources\views\layouts\inicio\home.blade.php)
```

even having the "laravelcollective/html" and it configuration

what are the ways and the correct good way to do the image and css linking?

Answer (score 0):

You can use this:

```
{{ url('css/estilos.css')}}
```

It's a correct way to get images, CSS and js files.

Comment: Or `{{ asset('css/estilos.css')}}`, which may be a little bit more descriptive.